# Is it possible to duck to evade an enemy's attack?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

I was wondering. In Chivalry Medieval Warfare, is it possible to duck in order to get out of the way of an enemy's attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to dodge under certain attacks by ducking. This is most useful against horizontal attacks, which have little vertical coverage and tends to be aimed higher. Note this does not mean that horizontal attacks will always miss, a properly angled attack will still hit a crouching opponent.

You can further reduce your vertical hitbox by looking down while ducking, this will cause your character's head to bend downwards.

Comment: I'd like to note...this really, really ruins the immersion of this game unlike anything else. Both doing and seeing it. A lot of the fun of the game is RP, pretending you're an old school knight/warrior. You may even notice a trend of people bowing to each other before engaging in one on one fights (Chivalry anyone? Whoops...). Coming across someone crouched in full armor spinning at mach 10 while hitting you with their back faced towards you just...isn't fun. Even if you dominate them and their silly antics, it feels ridiculous. To each his own, do it if you must, but I hope you don't lol...

Comment: "hitting you with their back faced towards you" that's in reference to players who crouch AND use their RB overhead swing to hit you while facing backwards. ;) (Hey to be fair I don't find just simple crouch/ducks so bad, just the "hey I'm a crab look at me spin on the ground" type deals lol)